# How can rsync compression help if the device is an ordinary disk?

Tags: rsync

The rsync man page explains the `z` in

```
rsync -avz foo:src/bar /data/tmp
```

by saying

> Additionally, compression will be used to reduce the size of data
> portions of the transfer.

How can rsync compression help if the device is an ordinary disk? I
understand that transmitting the compressed file reduces the bandwidth
of the backup, but wouldn't the subsequent decompression require two
additional trips of the same data to the CPU? Is the `z` flag meant for
intelligent backup devices that can decompress "on site"?

##### Context

`Disk Utility` on macOS refuses to run a full "First Aid" and warns me that I should back-up my drive. The drive is already on two Time Capsules, but since these are sealed under Time Machine and not "hacker-friendly", I grab a 1TB SSD as a backup of last resort and run

```
rsync -avz ~/ /Volumes/Mayday >> /tmp/filelist 2>&1
```

On USB 3 the ~500GB data should take 13.5 minutes (theoretical/ideal number, of course). Yet rsync is not done after 4 hours. How could rsync's overhead be that bad? Might the `-z` option be a particularly stupid option, forcing useless de/compression and transmission cycles?

###### Why am I using `rsync` rather than simple `cp`?

From experience a failing disk can bail out during file copying. Using rsync enables me to restart, if necessary, from where the preceding rsync has left off.

Comment: rsync is primarily intended to transfer/sync files between different computers (the "r" is short for "remote"), and some of its features (like compression) are only useful when running in this mode. See [my answer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/617476/leveraging-rsync-for-a-local-copy-between-two-slow-drives-benefits-without-a-da/617505#617505) for more details.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I added a 'context' and an answer to your question.

Comment: Compression is likely only relevant on a network connection. Within the computer it's not going to help, as each device needs to read and write "raw", assuming the filesystem itself doesn't have compression, as is the case with ZFS deployed with certain options.

Comment: `rsync` might not be the tool you need here, as there are aspects to a typical macOS deploy it can't always understand or replicate correctly. Apple offers a few solutions, one being Time Machine, but the other is creating a whole drive image using Disk Utility. This is much easier to restore onto a different device. A third party alternative is [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com/) which is an even more capable tool, mostly because it gives you more options than simple images.

Comment: If you're really in a bind, a lower-level tool like `dd` might help, as it can be set to retry on stubborn blocks. One thing I'd advise is if you have a good set of Time Machine backups, then disconnect those when wrecking around with low-level cloning so you don't accidentally blow one of those up by clicking the wrong thing.

Comment: I would also not recommend `rsync` for this. Recent versions of macOS have a split system volume layout, where there are actually two volumes (one for static system files, one for user/maleable data), with firmlinks connecting them (see [this Eclectic Light Co explainer](https://eclecticlight.co/2021/01/13/big-sur-boot-volume-layout/)). `rsync` does not understand this, and will not copy it correctly. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if it's seeing the same files at multuple places in the filesystem hierarchy (due to firmlinks), and hence making multiple copies of the same thing.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Right. In the final verdict rsync does say "some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/..."

Comment: @GordonDavisson It also says that it "sent 450 MB  received 20 MB   18 MB/sec". Perhaps the "received" part suggests the compression was indeed skipped. But that still does not explain the miserable speed.